# what happens when you have multiple instances of a services listening on a topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

My understanding is that Spring-kafka manages concurrency within a service. i.e. a listener will only consume messages from an assigned partition.

Is this also the case when there are multiple instances of a service (possibly with it's own set of listeners)?

e.g. 2 instances of service with 3 listeners each (all in the same group), consuming from a topic with 6 partitions.

Comment: If the instances do not share the consumer group, each service will read all the data independently. Each consumer will read from 2 partitions.

Comment: If they are in the same group, who assigns the partitions to consumers in different service instances?

Comment: The broker will. The consumer says --> hey, i want to consume, my group is bla bla. And the broker --> ok, so there was a consumer from your group, let's see how can we share the work.-- And starts something called rebalancing, which means deciding which partitions will each consumer read. f.e: you had one consumer from group A consuming 6 partitions. Now new consumer from group A comes, and tells that wants to consume as well. Kafka rebalances, revokes 3 partitions from the first consumer and tells him now to read partitions (1,3,5), and second consumer to read from (2,4,6). Just an example.

Comment: how about when concurrency is set on a spring-kafka listener? Is that also managed by the broker?

Comment: @aran, you should transform your comment to an answer, because it finally made me understand, how the balancing exactly works

Answer (score 0):

Answer from AI (Bing), which is quite accurate:

**Q:**
With spring boot microservice and spring-kafka, if my topic has two partitions and I set the concurrency to 2, what would happen if I start a second service instance? Will there be 4 consumers in the same group and 2 of them starves?

**A:**
In a Spring Boot microservice with Spring-Kafka, if your topic has two partitions and you set the concurrency to 2, it means that you have two threads in your KafkaListener, each of which can consume from a separate partition.

When you start a second service instance, it will also create two more consumers (assuming the same configuration). These consumers will join the same consumer group. However, since there are only two partitions for the topic, and each partition can only be consumed by one consumer in a group at a time, two of the consumers will not receive any messages. This is because Kafka’s consumer protocol will trigger a rebalance when a new consumer joins a consumer group, and during this rebalance, Kafka will try to assign the topic partitions among all consumers in the group to achieve load balancing.

So, in your scenario, you will indeed have 4 consumers in the same group, but 2 of them will not receive any messages as long as the other two consumers are alive and consuming messages. This is often referred to as “starvation” in the context of consumer groups. If one of the active consumers goes down, Kafka will trigger another rebalance and one of the “starving” consumers will start receiving messages.

Please note that this behavior is based on Kafka’s design to ensure that each message in a partition is consumed in order. If you want to increase throughput, you might consider increasing the number of partitions in your topic. But remember, more partitions may lead to more rebalances, which could impact performance. It’s important to find a balance based on your specific use case.